# how to place inputs in one line using bootstrap and form-horizontal?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap's form-horizontal form layout, so my fields appear each in new "line".

```
form.form-horizontal(role='form')
    fieldset(ng-disabled='queryInProgress')
        .form-group
            label.col-lg-2.control-label(for='Prefix') label
            .col-lg-4
                input.form-control(type='text', form-control)
                input.form-control(type='checkbox', form-control)
                input.form-control.input-sm(type='text', form-control)
```

[image: Rendered layout]

I however need these inputs ("Container name", checkbox, and following input field) to form one line and I can not easily find a "boostrap" way of doing this. The rest of the form. not shown here, I need to keep form-horizontal layout (I am aware of form-inline thing). How I can make three mentioned controls to appear inline using bootrstap classes?

JsFiddle with tentative look: http://jsfiddle.net/2UEZ6/

Comment: HTML & CSS in a Jsfiddle.net or Codepen,io example please.

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/2UEZ6/